# window.addEventListener('load', function) not working in react(gatsby)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, parallax

I'm struggling with stucking scroll parallax when page initial scroll is not at the top on load. Im using react-scroll-parallax library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-parallax).
To fix my problem i'm trying to use their suggestion from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-parallax#example-usage-of-context.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useController } from 'react-scroll-parallax';

const ParallaxCache = () => {
  const { parallaxController } = useController();
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      parallaxController.update();
      console.log(1);
    };
    window.addEventListener('load', handler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('load', handler);
  }, [parallaxController]);

  return null;
};

export default ParallaxCache;
```

I put ParallaxCache component at top of my app(page actually, cause its gatsby).

But the 'load' event doesnt seems to work. I've also tried 'DOMContentLoaded' but with the same result. However other event like for example 'scroll' or 'resize' works properly and my controller updates. Am I missing something or react prevents from using this events?

Answer (score 7):

If it's just the `load` event that's not working, it's possible that the page has already loaded when this code is being run.
Try adding an if statement to check whether the document is already loaded.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useController } from 'react-scroll-parallax';

const ParallaxCache = () => {
  const { parallaxController } = useController();
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      parallaxController.update();
      console.log(1);
    };

    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      handler();
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('load', handler);
      return () => document.removeEventListener('load', handler);
    }
  }, [parallaxController]);

  return null;
};

export default ParallaxCache;
```

Answer (score 4):

The useEffect hook is not appropriate in this situation, so you have to use useLayoutEffect hook.
Please check this reference.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-parallax#example-usage-of-context
You used useEffect hook 
But in this example, they used useLayoutEffect hook.
Please reference this reference.
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect

```
const ParallaxCache = () => {
    const { parallaxController } = useController();

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const handler = () => parallaxController.update();
        window.addEventListener('load', handler);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('load', handler);
    }, [parallaxController]);

    return null;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the function works now but it still dont fix my problem that parallax is stuck. It seems that the update() doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that **your window has already fired the *load* event** while your component is istantiated.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  handler();
} else {
  window.addEventListener('load', handler);
  return () => document.removeEventListener('load', handler);
}
```

This will cause intermittent issue, due to script not fully loaded.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should use one of the life cycle method if you use class based component like componentDidMount method.

```js
componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
}
```